# Issues with tkinter grid and pack in separate classes

Tags: python, tkinter

So I've been working on a group project, some of use used pack and others used grid as a layout manager, I'm making the part of the application that puts everyones code together.

I've been working on a UI using pack, and what I want it to do is when I click on a button, a new tk.Tk() window is launched which then runs its code that is managed by grid.

Here is a snipped of the code to try and show you what I'm doing, I keep getting the error "cannot use the geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack"

```
def launchQuest(self, questType):
    if(questType == "ham"):
        ham = tk.Tk()
        ham.configure(background='white')
        app = HM(ham)
        ham.mainloop()
```

If you need to see more code just ask, the whole class is around 400 lines so far but I don't think it is relevant.

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: There should be only one Tk() root window. If you want other windows, use toplevel widget.

Comment: Marcin I love you, thank you so much, I don't know how I got this far without even knowing about that - thanks again! (Too bad I had already just converted all of their code to pack! But it fixed a different issue for me regardless!)

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help. I will just make the official answer from my comment, so ppl know the question is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my first comment above, the answer is:

> There should be only one `Tk()` root window. If you want other windows,
>   use `Toplevel` widget.

Comment: You might want to provide a citation where that quote can be read in context. Is that from a user guide? Another SO question?

Comment: @BryanOakley Thx. Just added the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Only one type of positioning (grid, pack, or place) can be used at a time, within a container.  Tk() gives you a window (Toplevel) which you use to contain other widgets, some of which can be containers themselves, like Frame, for example.  You can pack two frames into a window, but you could not pack one frame and place another into the same window.  This limitation only applies one level deep – you could place a frame, and then pack a frame inside that, and then grid inside that, if you wanted.  It doesn't matter what method was used to position the container, only at the level of things directly contained by that container.